# How to find a parent with a known class in plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Please look at this html code first:

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <!-- Some code here -->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent>
  <!-- some code here -->
</div>
```

Suppose, I'm in "child" class, & I need to get the closest parent class of a "child". Remember, there are more than one "parent" class, I just need the closest "parent" only  using plain JavaScript, **without using JQuery.**

How to do that?

Comment: Why do you think that there is more than more parent class? The second ```<div class="child">``` is a sibling of ```<div class="child">```.

Comment: May be I'm mistaken at somewhat point. But Here, "parent" is className, not the parent you are thinking about. @Tom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using [**`closest()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.child').forEach(function(child){
  console.log(child.closest('.parent'));
});
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <!-- Some code here -->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <!-- some code here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper function and resuse it.Hope this is what you are looking for -

```js
let getParentClass = node => {
  return node.parentNode.classList.value;
}

let child = document.querySelectorAll('.child')[0]; // find the node
console.log(getParentClass(child));
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">

  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <!-- Some code here -->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <!-- some code here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parentNode` to get the closest parent. Or you can use `closest` from vanilla js.

```
const child = document.querySelector('.child');
const closestParent = child.parentNode;
```

```js
const child = document.querySelector('.child');
const closestParent = child.parentNode;
console.log(closestParent);

// Or you can use closest
const closest = child.closest('.parent');

console.log(closest);
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <!-- Some code here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">

  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <!-- Some code here -->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <!-- some code here -->
</div>
<script>
const child = document.getElementsByClassName('child')[0];
console.log(child)
const parent = child.closest('.parent');
console.log(parent)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
var parent = document.querySelectorAll(".child");
for(var p = 0; p < parent.length; p++) {
    parent[p].parentElement.classList.add("newClass");
    //parent[p].//do something
}
```

or directly quote the parent

```
var parent = document.querySelectorAll(".child");
for(var p = 0; p < parent.length; p++) {
    parent[p].closest(".parent").classList.add("newClass");
    //parent[p].closest(".parent").//do something
}
```